# How to resolve 80180026 error when trying to join laptop to Azure Domain

Tags: azure, windows-10, azure-active-directory

I'm getting "error code 80180026" when trying to join at T480s Lenovo to Azure.
Win10 ver1803 build17134.648
- ccmsetup.exe has been uninstalled from this formerly domain joined machine. - admittedly, when i first tried to join yesterday i had not deleted the machine from the local AD- but i subsequently did and it's been 18+hrs since it was deleted.
The device name is not showing in the Azure portal, and the device has never been renamed.

i was able to join another Win10,ver1803,build17134.68 machine today (a T470s Lenovo) without any issue. only had to wait 10 mins after i unjoined that laptop from the domain, deleted it from AD, and restarted the laptop.

i used the same credentials on both machines when setting up the join

per above, since this machine previously had sccm installed, i've uninstalled ccmsetup.exe, unjoined from the domain, deleted the machine from Active Driectory and made sure it was also gone from the Azure AD Device list.

per above, i was able to join another machine today with the same Win10 build and version- only difference is the Lenovo model (T480s is failing, T470s worked)

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when there are remnants of Intune still installed on the device.

1. Check `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\OnlineManagement\Common` and ensure that there is nothing remaining from Intune installed in that folder.
2. Keep a copy of the commands you will extract. Open Regedit and go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` Then, scroll through all the key names and for any that have Intune take a copy of the UninstallString and paste the uninstall commands into the command prompt.
3. Search for "Intune" in regedit and delete any keys that have this in it.
4. Reinstall the Intune classic portal and retire the device.
5. Then follow the steps again to remove all Intune client components.
6. Retire/wipe all orphaned devices. http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/chsimmons/archive/2016/09/07/azure-ad-join-error-80180026/
7. Make sure that you are using the right admin credentials and that the on-premises UPN matches the AD user names.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if both of the below conditions exist:

- MDM auto-enrollment is enabled in Azure.
- Either the PC agent (the Intune agent) or the Configuration Manager
  client agent is installed on the Windows 10 computer.

To resolve this issue, either disable MDM auto-enrollment in Azure, or uninstall the PC agent or SCCM client agent. This issue and resolution is describe in details here https://ekhichdi.com/2019/08/16/joining-to-azure-active-directory-fails/